# Why can't I click on this link with a nested image in IE7?

Tags: css, image, xhtml, anchor

Open the following page in IE7 and try clicking on the image within the category boxes:

http://www.southwestmedical.com/category/Diagnostic-Products/354

As far as I can tell, I'm not doing anything outside of the scope of (X)HTML/CSS, why am I not able to click these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the `display: block` on the span surrounding the img.  Removed that and tweaked the styles to make it look the same and all is good now.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a known phenomenon:

- [**IE Image Link Fix**](http://drupal.org/node/116998)
- [**IE7-/Win: Not clickable image in a link (caused by hasLayout)**](http://www.brunildo.org/test/IEaL.html)

giving the `img` a `float: left` as well might help, and should cause no change in layout.

Comment: Adding a float: left; did not help.  Nor did any of the other CSS tricks mentioned in the link.  The javascript trick did, but this seems like a dirty hack and I'd rather not use it.